# Is there a way to only install MS word from MS office 2011 for the Mac OSX

Tags: macos, microsoft-word

Is there a way to just install MS word form the MS office 2011 on Mac OSX? If that is not possible is there way to at least get rid of the communicator, remote connection and messenger while installation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can customize your installation during the installation of MS Office. Just uncheck the parts you don't want.

Answer (score 0):

Run the installation to this point, then click the *Customize* button at the bottom of the window.

[image]

Uncheck anything you do not want to install.

[image]